# How can I add a "contains" criteria in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql, query, contains

I am running a simple query that takes First name, Last name, and email from a dataset. At the end of my query, I need to include to only pull the email addresses that contain ".com"

I currently have:

> Where Email__c like '.com'

However, this yields no data. How can I transform this in a "where email ends with '.com'" query?

Answer (score 3):

That would only find emails addresses that are only '.com'.

To match with email address values that are have one or more characters before the '.com' text, you need to add a wildcard %.

Try using '%.com' , which would match any value that ends with '.com'